# Can anyone identify this caterpillar / cocoon?

Tags: zoology, entomology, species-identification

This insect is about 0.5 mm in length, so it is very small. It doesn't have legs I don't believe, I am not too good at this but I don't know if it's a worm or more like a cocoon for something.

I do find this alarming because I found this one underneath my bed sheet on the mattress. Now I do recall seeing something similar on the crack of the shaky tile floor, so I can't tell if it's just an apartment pest or it actually lives in mattresses.

Location: Toronto, Canada

[image: One side]

[image: Back side]

Answer (score 1):

It's carpet beetle larvae.
It's a serious pest, right behind the bedbug. The larvae were found on an old mattress.

I found about 4 more afterwards.

[image]

Comment: This could probably be many different species in the family Dermestidae, which often have fairly similar looking larvae. The carpet beetle is a good bet thought since many of the other common species feed on animal materials (food, insect collections, fur, leather etc.)